# LWC Import custom picklist field and show it in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lightning-combobox

I have a custom field (picklist) which is filled with a global picklist values.

I want to import it and show it on the screen in the form of combobox (or anything similiar).

What I am trying to do is:

```
import PICKLISTFIELD_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/MyObject.MyPicklistField';
```

```
<lightning-combobox options={PICKLISTFIELD_FIELD}>
</lightning-combobox>
```

I have literally no clue on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`getPicklistValues`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values) wire method is what you're looking for.

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc'
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi'
import PICKLIST_FIELD_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/MyObject.MyPicklistField'

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
  picklistValues = []

  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA',
    fieldApiName: PICKLIST_FIELD_FIELD,
  })
  getPicklistValuesForField({ data, error }) {
    if (error) {
      // TODO: Error handling
      console.error(error)
    } else if (data) {
      this.picklistValues = [...data.values]
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<lightning-combobox
  options={picklistValues}
></lightning-combobox>
```

> add the rest of the [props](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example) to the `<lightning-combobox/>` element for data binding.

Comment: So basically you mean it is not possible to import and show the field itself as a custom component in LWC, and getting its value and shoving it into the LWC combobox is the only way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Using the `<lightning-record-form/>` might be the approach you're looking for. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation